# I can't get my images to display in a single row on my website using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image

Having trouble getting my images to display in a single row on larger screen sizes. This is for a simple bioSite project that I am working on.

```html
<body>
  <div class="image-gallery">
    <div class="container">
      <figure>
        <img src="mattdee.jpg"width = "220" height = "220">
        <figcaption>Matthew & his wife Deanna</figcaption>
      </figure>
      
      <figure>
        <img src="mattzane.jpg"width = "220" height = "220">
        <figcaption>Matthew & his son Zane</figcaption>
      </figure>
      
      <figure>
        <img src="mattcarolinebiopic.jpg"width = "220" height = "220">
        <figcaption>Matthew & his daughter Caroline</figcaption>
      </figure> 
    </div>
            
    <div class= "container">
      <p>The things I love most in this life are my family,
         being creative and making music, 
         and my profession of engineering.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
.image-gallery{
  padding-left: 7%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the container to multiple divs for rows and columns allows you to use flex display property. This solution worked for me [heres an image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXVv7.png).

```html
<style>
    .image-gallery{
        padding-left: 7%;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    .column {
        flex: 33.33%; /* 1 / Number of Images */
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="image-gallery">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <figure width="100%">
                    <img src="img1.jpg"width = "220" height = "220">
                    <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        
            <div class="column">
                <figure width="100%">
                    <img src="img2.jpg"width = "220" height = "220">
                    <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        
            <div class="column">
                <figure width="100%">
                    <img src="img3.jpg"width = "220" height = "220">
                    <figcaption>Caption 3</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>The things I love most in this life are my family, being creative and making music, and my profession of engineering.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```